# ListView Customizado

Tags: android, listview

Galera, tenho um listview que carrega dados de um banco de dados. Esses dados são números em si, e gostaria de poder diferenciá-los. Tipo... se o número for zero gostaria de que ficasse de uma cor específica ou em negrito. Ou qualquer outra coisa que o diferenciasse dos outros que não são zero.

Alguém sabe como fazer? Poderia colocar um exemplo aqui?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Olha um tutorial bacana fera: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: Obrigado por responder @Luídne. Esse tutorial é muito bom... mas quero uma coisa que seja diferente e ao mesmo tempo comum. Tipo: todos os campos com números diferentes de zero na cor azul e todos campos com os número iguais a zero vermelho. Deu pra entender? rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer isto sobrescrevendo o [método `Adapter.html#getView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) no teu `adapter`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
   View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
   TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
   String text = textView.getText().toString();

   if (text.equals("0")) {
       view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
       //textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
   } else {
       view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);  
   }

   return view;  
}
```

<sub>[**Fonte**](http://droidgallery.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-list-view-with-alternating-row.html)</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Funcionou perfeitamente, valeu!
:D